# Do Django Models inherit managers? (Mine seem not to)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

I have 2 models:

```
class A(Model):
    #Some Fields
    objects = ClassAManager()

class B(A):
    #Some B-specific fields
```

I would expect `B.objects` to give me access to an instance of `ClassAManager`, but this is not the case....

```
>>> A.objects
<app.managers.ClassAManager object at 0x103f8f290>
>>> B.objects
<django.db.models.manager.Manager object at 0x103f94790>
```

Why doesn't `B` inherit the `objects` attribute from `A`?

Answer (score 2):

Your base class will need to be an abstract base class in order for the custom manager to be inherited, as described [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance)

Comment: This has changed as of Django 1.10 - managers are now always inherited apparently.

Comment: @Flash that's indeed what the doc seems to say but I can't reproduce the inheritance with non-abstract models :/

Answer (score 1):

As of Django 3.1, custom managers are inherited from the parent abstract base class. However there is a **very important caveat** - Unlike in normal classes, the child classes won't have the default `objects` manager. You will have to explicity set this on the parent abstract base class.

For example, this won't work

```
class AbstractBase(Model):
   # child fields come here

   custom_manager = MyCustomManager()

class Child(AbstractBase):
    # child fields come here
    pass

Child.objects.filter(id=1)
```

You will get this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Child' has no attribute 'objects'
```

Now the `Child` class only has 1 manager `custom_manager`, which becomes its default manager. If you would like to have `objects` as its default manager then you will have to explicitly declare this on the parent abstract base class.

```
from django.db.models import Manager, Model

class AbstractBase(Model):
   # child fields come here

   objects = Manager()
   custom_manager = MyCustomManager()
```